# Replacing words in Python?

Tags: python, string, decode, encode

I'm trying to replace the letters in key with the letters in alpha (and vice versa):

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
```

I am trying to change a string to become encoded (and the other way around), so say "Hello" would become "LTZZE". Any idea how to do this? This is my current code:

```
usrInput = 0
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

def menu():
    print "SECRET DECODER MENU"
    print ""
    print "1) Quit"
    print "2) Encode"
    print "3) Decode"
    usrInput = raw_input("What would you like to do?")

    return usrInput


def encodeWord():
    plain = plain.upper()
    length = len(plain)
    encode = plain.encode(alpha, key)

    return encode


def decodeWord():
    coded = coded.upper()
    length = len(coded)
    decode = coded.decode(key, alpha)

    return decode


def main():

    keepGoing = True

    while keepGoing:
        usrInput = menu()

        if usrInput == "2":
            plain = raw_input("Text you want to be encoded: ")
            encodeWord()
            print encode(plain)

        elif usrInput == "3":
            coded = raw_input("Code you need to be decyphered: ")
            decodeWord()
            print decode(coded)

        elif usrInput == "1":
            print "Thanks for doing super secret spy stuff with me. No one seems to want to anymore. Goodbye. ):"
            keepGoing = False

        else:
            print "I don't know what to do! Ahhh!"

main()
```

Comment: I hope this is just an excersice for fun or learning string operations. Because if it's not - those who are going to use it are in big trouble, as one-to-one replacement ciphers are crackable by pen and paper (and quite a bit of math).

Comment: @J0HN Don't worry, it's just an exercise for string manipulation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.maketrans](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.maketrans#str.maketrans) and [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.maketrans#str.translate). If you use Python 2 this functions are in `string` ([here (maketrans)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [here (translate)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)).

Example (python 3):

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
enc = str.maketrans(alpha, key)
usrInput = 'HELLO'
print(usrInput.translate(enc))
```

Example (python 2)

```
import string
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
enc = string.maketrans(alpha, key)
inp = 'HELLO'
print string.translate(inp, enc)
```

Output:

```
LTZZE
```

Comment: @user1775603 Oh, yes. I added now python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Note this is a homework assignment for a computer science class.  I created the assignment, and I'm aware it's on stack overflow.  If you turn it in as your own work, I will know.  You will earn a zero for the assignment and we will begin academic misconduct proceedings.

(If you're playing along at home, this is indeed a string manipulation assignment, and explicitly NOT to be considered a good cryptographic practice.  We also are not allowing maketrans() for this assignment, because it's a string manipulation and function exercise for beginning programmers.)

If you're really desperate for help, come see me or one of the recitation leaders we're paying to help you.